# How can I efficiently 'subclass' in external CSS?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, code-duplication

I have a box defined that works for most of my site:

```
.searchBox
{
    width: 610px;
    height: 170px;
    padding: 15px 55px 5px 15px;
    background: url('../images/advanced_search_BG.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

But I have one box that needs to be a little bigger; it has to be `height: 220px`.

I know I could duplicate the above, calling it, say `searchBoxLarge`, put that on my div tag, and be done.  But that's duplicate code that I don't want.

This might be a 'dumb question', but I'm not trained in CSS and looking for assistance...

What is the format to specify the `searchBoxLarge` with the `height: 220px`, but without duplicating the entire `searchBox` entry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `searchBoxLarge` to the `searchBox` declaration, and then make a separate declaration for just `searchBoxLarge` which overwrites the height value.

```
.searchBox, .searchBoxLarge
{
    width: 610px;
    height: 170px;
    padding: 15px 55px 5px 15px;
    background: url('../images/advanced_search_BG.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.searchBoxLarge
{
    height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: I think he needed the height to be 220px, not the width.

Comment: @AlanWeibel, he should only have to use .searchBoxLarge or .searchBox, never both

Comment: If you're adding both classes to the same element there is no need to select them both in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There was a good article about doing this on SitePoint http://www.sitepoint.com/first-look-object-oriented-css/

I would suggest you read the responses to the article since there are some drawbacks to doing your CSS like this, and also some benefits.

I agree the name Object Oriented CSS is misleading because there is no true sub-typing

Cheers! Orin